# Using XML entity representation in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am wondering how i can use entity representation to fill in the id in this code

```
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'msg_id='+ ID; 
//alert(ID);
var mssg = $('#'+&quot;ID&quot;').html();
$('#content').val(mssg);
```

My attempt `var mssg = $('#'+&quot;ID&quot;).html();` is wrong since the script won't work now.What's the correct way of doing this?.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? get the element with the id of ID and its conents?

Comment: I am trying to have $('#myid').html(); since i know the id.

Comment: Why are you using `&quot`?  What are you doing?

Comment: That code is what i am trying to use to have a '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mssg = $('#'+ID).html();
```

should be the correct way, if I understand your question.

Comment: That works,but i got to ask,why are the quotes not needed when putting in the variable?.

Comment: @flapjack: Because it's a variable.  You do it here: `var dataString = 'msg_id='+ ID`.

Comment: because your are basically concatenating two strings.

Comment: Variables are objects, so no need.